# intalling PHPUnit on Windows

Tags: phpunit

I have XAMPP 5.6.3 installed on Windows 32bits (PHP Version 5.6.3), and I want to install PHPUnit.

I followed the instruction in the official site of PHPUnit :

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.phar.windows

but when I run this line `phpunit --version` in the command line, I get this message :

```
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I have version 3.7.18 of PHPUnit running on windows XP on PHP 5.3.18. What version of windows (x32 or x64) are you using and what version of PHPUnit are you expecting to run under what version of PHP?.

Comment: Check that the CLI version of PHP.exe is in your PATH variable. Do not bother with PHPUnit until you can run PHP scripts files from anywhere via the CLI version of PHP. I suspect that is where the issue is.

Comment: @RyanVincent : windows 32bits and PHP Version 5.6.3

Comment: @RyanVincent this is my PATH variable : `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\Aimad\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\bin`

Comment: Go the directory where php is installed and run 'php --ini' from the command line. It will tell you where it is looking for 'configuration' info. The easiest way is to add the php directories to the 'path' variable. see 'my computer' -> properties -> 'environment variables'. You issue is almost certainly that the php.exe isn't found rather than anything to do with PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that PHP is not included in my PATH.
So I followed this solution :

1. Windows button + Pause
2. List item
3. Advanced System Settings
4. Environment Variables
5. append PHP installation dir to the PATH variable.

Comment: glad it is sorted out.